# Custom dialogs and porting wid in WiX

Tags: c++, dialog, wix

I have a custom dialog which has an extension wid (CustomDialog.wid) and has a helper library to go with it written in C++. The helper library searches for [SQL Servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) in the network and fills the combobox in the custom dialog. It also saves the server name or [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) so that it may be used by custom actions later.

Can I use this custom dialog directly in WiX or do I need to create a WiX supported custom dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert them into WiX format by building a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project and then using WiX's `dark.exe` to create a .wxs file. The output may or may not be completely useful but it's worth a try. You'd probably want to make the dialog size and layout are the same as any "built-in" WiX dialogs you might use in your new project.

Comment: Thanks, I can now use the dialog code instead of creating the dialog from the scratch.